# Is it possible to create a SURFACE PLOT with this dataset?

Tags: r, data-visualization

I am new at software programming and I am starting to program some 3D graphs. 
I have this dataset

```
σA    Leverage   PDPV
18.27%  35.78%  0.04%
3.10%   93.53%  1.07%
12.17%  50.15%  0.03%
2.99%   93.94%  1.56%
7.96%   75.61%  0.08%
18.37%  30.97%  0.00%
15.99%  41.97%  0.05%
8.72%   68.19%  0.27%
2.63%   91.55%  0.13%
16.24%  41.68%  0.02%
9.16%   63.56%  0.02%
21.47%  50.97%  5.16%
18.97%  15.03%  0.00%
8.91%   70.24%  0.14%
7.44%   74.18%  0.08%
8.55%   72.90%  0.32%
13.55%  37.98%  0.00%
21.62%  14.15%  0.00%
9.69%   62.92%  0.02%
14.64%  50.47%  0.16%
17.12%  55.80%  2.64%
14.25%  63.05%  1.15%
10.34%  74.29%  0.67%
10.05%  71.27%  0.55%
16.28%  30.83%  0.00%
9.94%   80.67%  6.47%
31.07%  32.35%  2.69%
```

I would like to know if it is possible to use a 3D Surface Plot for these three variables. If it is not, can you please give me explain why not and provide a suggestion?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please explain the *purpose* of your plotting: what are you trying to learn about these variables?

Comment: The CRAN graphics Task View has a wealth of links to R packages which as the name suggests do graphics. One of them should fit the bill.

Answer (score 0):

I supposed that you just want a surface plot using three variables as xyz. I suggest using R (and rgl and geometry packages) to you.
Here is my example in R (I simply just made triangle mesh and painted it):

```
# reading your data
data <- structure(list(theta_A = c(18.27, 3.1, 12.17, 2.99, 7.96, 18.37, 15.99, 8.72, 2.63, 16.24, 9.16, 21.47, 18.97, 8.91, 7.44, 
                                   8.55, 13.55, 21.62, 9.69, 14.64, 17.12, 14.25, 10.34, 10.05, 16.28, 9.94, 31.07), 
                       Leverage = c(35.78, 93.53, 50.15, 93.94, 75.61, 30.97, 41.97, 68.19, 91.55, 41.68, 63.56, 50.97, 15.03, 70.24, 
                                    74.18, 72.9, 37.98, 14.15, 62.92, 50.47, 55.8, 63.05, 74.29, 71.27, 30.83, 80.67, 32.35), 
                       PDPV = c(0.04, 1.07, 0.03, 1.56, 0.08, 0, 0.05, 0.27, 0.13, 0.02, 0.02, 5.16, 0, 0.14, 0.08, 0.32, 0, 0, 
                                0.02, 0.16, 2.64, 1.15, 0.67, 0.55, 0, 6.47, 2.69)),
                  .Names = c("theta_A", "Leverage", "PDPV"), row.names = c(NA, -27L), class = "data.frame")


# As far as I see your data, theta_A x PDPV (xz plane)'s sideview is the most simple 
# and don't have duplication. So I use 2D (xz) Delaunay triangulation to make your data a tessellation.

library(rgl); library(geometry)

tri <- t( delaunayn(data[,c(1,3)]) )           # making connection information
open3d()                                       # open a RGL device
plot3d(data, type="s", col="red", radius=0.5)  # 3D scatter plot
rgl.triangles(data[tri,1], data[tri,2], data[tri,3], col = "gray", alpha=0.8)  # painting triangle mesh
```

[image]